# How to add data-testid attribute to react-select components

Tags: react-select, react-testing-library

Using react-testing-library, I wish to test a form implemented in React.

That form includes a React component of type react-select.

It is necessary to click a part of the react-select component that has no label, no text, etc.  (E.g. the dropdown arrow).

Ordinarily, the react-testing-library way to do this is to add a 'data-testid' attribute to the item in question.

I've found that it's possible to give each part of the react-select a CSS class attribute, by providing the 'classNamePrefix' prop to the react-select component.  Is there some way to do the same for data-testid attribute?

Note: I'm aware I can provide custom implementations of the components of react-select, but that seems like overkill to get one attribute in place.

Comment: You might instead want to use react-select-event, which is a library specifically built for testing react-select components with react-testing-library: https://github.com/romgain/react-select-event

Answer (score 12):

First of all I'd question why there's no label on the `Select` as this wouldn't be classed as accessible for screen readers.

But, If you don't want a visible label you could always pass an `aria-label` prop to the `Select` and test it that way using getByLabelText.

```
<Select aria-label="Example Label" ... />
```

```
getByLabelText('Example Label')
```

If you really need to add a `data-testid` you could replace the specific components you want to add the `data-testid` too and add it. ([See the docs for more info](https://react-select.com/components#replacing-components))

e.g.

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import EmojiIcon from '@atlaskit/icon/glyph/emoji';
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import { colourOptions } from './docs/data';

const DropdownIndicator = props => {
  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
      <span data-testid="DropdownIndicator">
        <EmojiIcon primaryColor={colourOptions[2].color} />
      </span>
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[4], colourOptions[5]]}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
  />
);
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-4qw3r)

Answer (score 0):

Before all `react-select` is just a select. In testing you should keep eyes in your components. `react-select` is a component outside your project, the test cases belong to their owner.

So in this cases I recommend to just mock the package in your benefit.

Here is an example of how to mock it:

```
jest.mock('react-select', () => ({ options, value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <select data-testid="react-select-mock" defaultValue={value} onChange={onChange}>
      {options.map(({ label, value }) => (
        <option key={value} value={value}>
          {label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
});
```